# Single quote is being replaced by two single quotes automatically in java while creating a filename

Tags: java, mysql, openlaszlo

I am facing a strange problem while creating a file in java using MYSQL.

My code:

```
String lChildSql = this.lSQLBucket.select("get.child.by.name")
                        .replace("LEFT").with(lLeft)
                        .replace("RIGHT").with(lRight)
                        .replace("LEVEL").with(lLevel + 1)
                        .replace("NAME").with(pName).get()
                    ResultSet lChildRs = lDB.Qry(lChildSql);
```

Sample:If i create a file with pName raj'sek'har and its being created  as raj"sek"har automatically.

please help me in solving this issue.

Regards,

Raj

Comment: Can you post all the code you're using?

Comment: Can you verify, that it isn't two single quotes? Doesn't SQL often use two single quotes, to mask an apostrophe?

Comment: Hi @user unknown , Yes its being replaced by two single quotes and its not double quote...how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what user unknown is saying is that this is normal behaviour.  it's how sql deals with a single quote (apostrophe) inside a word.

sql uses single quotes for strings - `'this is a string'` - but if your string includes a single quote then it will cause problems - `'this isn't going to work'` - because the string "ends early".

so what sql does is replace that with a two single apostrophes, which is an "escape sequence" to indicate that actually, a single single apostrophe [sic] is required: `'this''ll work fine'`.

note that this is only for display.  it's not "really" replacing anything, and when you retrieve the data, everything will be fine.

[someone else saying the same thing](http://www.kamath.com/codelibrary/cl003_apostrophe.asp)